# How can I know when ItemsSource changes?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, scrollto

How can I know when items are added to or removed from an `ItemsControl`.  I need to scroll to the top when this happens.  I know there is another post on here for doing this using behavior injection, but this doesn't work for me.  `ScrollToTop` is called but the result is not scrolled to the top.   Is there another way to do this MVVM style without behavior injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here:
[MSDN Forums (similar question with answers)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/969a88f2-a834-4443-8c32-e656052db945)
Or here:
[MSDN Documentation (OnItemsSourceChanged method)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.onitemssourcechanged.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could raise an event when ItemsSource is touched, listen for that event, and call ScrolToTop when that event is raised.