# WPF ListView with ItemsSource: how to know when model adds item

Tags: wpf, listview, itemssource

Question: What is "proper" way of letting the user control's "view model" (.xaml.cs file) know that a ListViewItem has been added to a ListView? Note that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890559/how-can-i-know-when-itemssource-changes) is addresses a different problem.

Details:

I have a UserControl which contains a ListView and a DataContext:

1. The ListView has an ItemsSource={Binding ActionLogEntries}
2. ActionLogEntries is an ObservableCollection property in the DataContext

The data context adds items to the ListView when certain things happen.

But there isn't a ListView.ItemAdded event. There is a CollectionChanged event on ObservableCollection in data context but the view model's handler of this event could get called before the item is added to the ListView so this doesn't seem like a good strategy.

FYI: This came up because when items are added to the ListView, it doesn't automatically scroll to the newly added item, which is behavior I have to add. Presumably I'd use ScrollIntoView after that.

Comment: What about handling the [ItemsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.itemschanged.aspx) event of the ListView's [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx)? Perhaps still too early...

Comment: This seems to work. However, the event arg is a little strange: the e.Position is a position generator, with Index and Offset properties and it looks like you have to add index+offset if you are interested in the latest element added. More details below.

Answer (score 1):

So there are at least two ways of skinning this cat:

1. do as explained by Clemens in comment to my question
2. do as in [this post by WPF Mentor](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2008/11/notification-when-items-are-added-or.html)

Solution 1 seems more natural for the event subscription, since you don't need to cast; also IntelliSense doesn't show class members of implemented interfaces without cast, so for Solution 2 you have to remember to look at what interfaces are implemented and check for events there too. Here is what the subscription looks like for each solution:

```
protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInitialized(e);

    // Solution 1, subscription:
    xActionListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged +=
        new ItemsChangedEventHandler(ActionLog_ItemsChanged);

    // Solution 2, subscription:
    ((INotifyCollectionChanged)xActionListView.Items).CollectionChanged += 
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ActionListView_CollectionChanged);
}
```

But solution 2 has easier to use event arg in handler:

```
// Solution 1, handler: 
private void ActionLog_ItemsChanged(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        // Solution 1, scroll the new item into view  
        xActionListView.ScrollIntoView(
            xActionListView.Items[e.Position.Index + e.Position.Offset]);
    }      
}

// Solution 2, handler: 
private void ActionListView_CollectionChanged(
    object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        // Solution 2, scroll the new item into view  
        xActionListView.ScrollIntoView(e.NewItems[0]);
    }      
}
```

It looks like in some circumstances, one solution may be more appropriate than the other: the event data may be easier to use in one or the other based on what data you need.